# How do a fix the cpan command when the SQLite index fails?

Tags: perl, sqlite, cpan

When attempting to use the CPAN command line, I am unable to either reload index or install any modules. There is an error with SQLite. If I disable the use of SQLite, I get a different error. Both are listed below. Has anyone found this problem before? How did you fix it?

"""WITH SQLITE"""

```
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Creating database file ...

Gathering information from index files ...
fetch_info() failed! at C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/CPAN/SQLite/Index.pm line
57, <DATA> line 58.
Indexing failed! at C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/CPAN/SQLite.pm line 62,  <DATA> line 58. CPAN::SQLite setup failed at C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/CPAN/SQLite/META.pm l ine 329, <DATA> line 58. Catching error: "system C:\\strawberry\\perl\\bin\\perl.exe -MCPAN::SQLite::META =setup,update -e setup failed: 5632 at C:\\strawberry\\perl\\vendor\\lib/CPAN/SQ Lite/META.pm line 323.\cJ" at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/CPAN.pm line 391 CPAN::shell() called at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/App/Cpan.pm line 295 App::Cpan::_process_options('App::Cpan') called at C:/strawberry/perl/li b/App/Cpan.pm line 364 App::Cpan::run('App::Cpan') called at C:\strawberry\perl\bin/cpan line 8 """USERANDPASS""" 
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Creating database file ...

Gathering information from index files ...
fetch_info() failed! at C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/CPAN/SQLite/Index.pm line
57, <DATA> line 58.
Indexing failed! at C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/CPAN/SQLite.pm line 62, <DATA>
 line 58.
CPAN::SQLite setup failed at C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/CPAN/SQLite/META.pm l
ine 329, <DATA> line 58.
Catching error: "system C:\\strawberry\\perl\\bin\\perl.exe -MCPAN::SQLite::META
=setup,update -e setup failed: 5632 at C:\\strawberry\\perl\\vendor\\lib/CPAN/SQ
Lite/META.pm line 323.\cJ" at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/CPAN.pm line 391
        CPAN::shell() called at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/App/Cpan.pm line 295
        App::Cpan::_process_options('App::Cpan') called at C:/strawberry/perl/li
b/App/Cpan.pm line 364
        App::Cpan::run('App::Cpan') called at C:\strawberry\perl\bin/cpan line 8
```

"""WITHOUT SQLITE"""

```
Going to read 'C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz'
Warning: Your C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does
not contain a Line-Count header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Warning: Your C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does
not contain a Last-Updated header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Could not split line["\cI<head>"]
...Could not split line["\cI</head>"]
Could not split line["\cI<body bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">"]
Could not split line["\cI<script language=\"javascript\">"]
Giving up parsing your C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt
.gz, too many errorsGoing to read 'C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.t
xt.gz'
............................................................................DONE

Going to read 'C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz'
Warning: Your C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does
not contain a Line-Count header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Warning: Your C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does
not contain a Last-Updated header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Could not split line["\cI<head>"]
...Could not split line["\cI</head>"]
Could not split line["\cI<body bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">"]
Could not split line["\cI<script language=\"javascript\">"]
Giving up parsing your C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt
.gz, too many errorsLockfile removed.
```

Comment: I haven't run into this error before, but it looks as though some of the CPAN module metadata might be corrupted.  It might be worth a shot to uninstall and then reinstall Strawberry Perl and then see if the error persists.

Comment: Gave that a shot, but it didn't work. I'm not sure why SQLite isn't working, but I'm beginning to think using without the SQLite is a network rights issue. The temp files are pulling a intranet error page instead of the CPAN module page it should be.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with the inner workings of CPAN, but I believe it uses SQLite as the main means of storing module metadata.  I do know that when you invoke `cpan` from the command line and tell it to install a module, it does connect to `cpan.org` to download the module.  If you have limited network rights, then this could be an issue.  I'd recommend talking to your sysadmin.

Comment: The firewall settings are blocking access. :( Unfortunately that's the only answer I have. Can't change the network firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reinstall Strawberry anytime you have a problem. I know this is Windows, but life is better than that. Try deleting *C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz*, which appears to be corrupted. CPAN.pm should re-download it if it is missing.

Comment: I did that as well. This is a fresh install to begin with, so I did try a full reinstall as well as deleting the corrupted file. The issue is with the network connection, at least without SQLite. The network firewall is burning the request as an unauthorized user, even with admin rights.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found the answer on [this](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.win32.vanilla/2008/12/msg83.html) site. The problem can be solved by temporarily suspending the use of SQLite by CPAN and then updating the module that it uses it with. From the command line:

```
cpan
cpan> o conf use_sqlite 0
cpan> o conf commit
cpan> reload index
cpan> install CPAN::SQLite
cpan> o conf use_sqlite 1
cpan> o conf commit
cpan> ...
```